# Get the vertex names of an edge

Tags: r, igraph

when I use "E(hu)[12]" for selecting a vertex I get the following output:

```
[12] A  -- B
```

Now I need the names for these two vertices. How can I select the names/labels "A" and "B"?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `inc()` when indexing a vertex set, to get the incident vertices of an edge. This is probably the most readable:

```
# Some example data
library(igraph)
hu <- graph.ring(20)
V(hu)$name <- letters[1:20]

V(hu)[ inc(12) ]
# Vertex sequence:
# [1] "l" "m"

V(hu)[ inc(12) ]$name
# [1] "l" "m"
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I could finally figure it out

```
V(g)[get.edges(hu, E(g)[12])[1]]
V(g)[get.edges(hu, E(g)[12])[2]]
```

Seems a bit too complex but it works...